# bash: get path from current directory given sub-directory name

Tags: linux, bash, macos

Trying to write a script to clean up environment files after a resource is deleted. The problem is all the script is given as input is the name of the resource (this cannot be changed) with zero identifying information beyond that. **How can I find the path of the directory the resource is sitting in?**

The directory is set up a bit like the following, although much more extensive. All of these are directories, not files. There can be as many as 40+ directories to search, but the desired one is generally not more than 2-3 directories deep.

```
foo
    aaa
       aaa_green
       aaa_blue
    bbb
    ccc
       ccc_green
bar
    ddd
    eee
       eee_green
       eee_blue
    fff
       fff_green
       fff_blue
       fff_pink
```

I might be handed input like `aaa_green` or just `ddd`.

As an example, given `eee_blue` as input, I need to know `eee_blue`'s path from the working directory so I can cd there and delete the directory. IE, I would expect to return `bar/eee/eee_blue/` or `bar/eee/`, either is acceptable.

The "best" option I can see currently is to cd into the lowest level of each directory via multiple greps, get each's contents and look for a match, and when it does (eventually) match save that cd'ing as the path. This frankly sounds awful and inefficient.

The only other alternative method I could think of was a straight recursive grep, but I tested it and at 8 minutes it still hadn't finished running.

This script needs to run on **both mac and linux**, although in a desperate pinch I could go linux only.

Comment: Isn't that `find . -name 'eee_blue'`, possibly printing the name, possibly using `-exec rm -fr {} +`, or something similar?  The fundamental seems to be 'use the `find` command'.  Were you unaware of that, or is there a reason not to use it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Bash noob, had zero idea find existed. That's nifty! Feel free to answer so I can accept, that looks like my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Unix tool for doing this sort of task is the [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) command.  The GNU version of [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) has more extensive options than the POSIX specification (by quite a margin).  The version on macOS Sierra (and Mac OS X) is similar to the GNU version.  I found an online manual for OS X 10.9 at [Apple `find`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html), but there's probably a better location somewhere.

It looks like you might want to run:

```
find . -name 'eee_blue'
```

which will print the names of matching files or directories, or perhaps:

```
find . -name 'eee_blue' -exec rm -fr {} +
```

which will run the `rm -fr` command on each name.  You can run a custom script you create in place of `rm -fr` if you prefer; if the logic is complex, it's what I do.

Be ***extremely*** cautious before using `rm -fr` automatically!